# FormattedNumber component from react-intl doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I am trying to use the component `FormattedNumber` from the `react-intl` library but I can't make it to work.

```
<IntlProvider
    locale="en-US"
    messages={locales['en-US']}
>
    <div>
        <FormattedNumber value={123456} />
        <FormattedNumber value="123456" />
    </div>
</IntlProvider>
```

This only returns the value the way I passed it to the component, wrapped with a span, but it doesn't format the number.

I get an error in the console:

> [React Intl] Error formatting number.
>    TypeError: Bind must be called on a function

The `FormattedMessage` component works fine for all my translations, 
the locale is set to `en-US`, so I don't think the issue comes from the `IntlProvider` or something else.

[image]

I am using the latest version of the library, `2.0.1`

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe value={12345} should be enclosed to quotes? and BTW from docs : "By default <FormattedNumber> will render the formatted number into a <span>"

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. In my case problem was in global definition window.Intl. It rewrite the original lib object and lose functions context